# Check that record doesn't exist/retrieve existing record active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord, rails-postgresql

This question has two parts:

Consider an active record relation that has a `Student` -  `name:string, favorite_class:references` and `FavoriteClass` `name:string, abbrev:string`.

First question: When creating a `student` record and adding a `favorite class`  (name and abbrev) I want to check if that name/abbrev combo exists and if it does load that one for this association, else create a new one.

Second: When I try to update (Put) the `student` I want to be able to pass the `abbrev` of the `favorite class` and look up the record by that portion (assuming abbrevs are unique) and use that, else fail.

I am not seeing the rails way of doing this type of operation.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the trick is to use [find_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) method:

```
#in the place where you create a new Student
#this method return first entity from db, if it doesn't found, will create one
fav_class = FavoriteClass.find_or_create(name: some_name, abbrev: some_abbrev)
Student.create(name: some_student_name, favorite_class: fav_class)
```

something similar you can do for your second question. Please, give me more details about it.

**Update 1**

If you want to update student's favourite class, you can do it in this way:

```
#I assume that you use latest vertion of rails of not, use .first instead of .take
new_class = FavoriteClass.where(abbrev: some_abbrev).take
student.update_attributes(favorite_class: new_class) if new_class
```

Comment: For example I need to make a put request that accepts an abbrev and will load the class based on that abbrev and update the student record.